# Change text value of JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

There is a method to change value of ApproveButtonText

But I cant figure out how to change value of "Cancel" button.. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html

I dont want to use JFileChooser#setLocale(Locale) because I need custom text on this button.

Here is how to set for Approve option, but there is nothing for Cancel option.

```
JFileChooser Filechoose = new JFileChooser();
Filechoose.setApproveButtonText("Other text");
```

Just to cler my question little bit more. I want only one occurrence of JFileChoose to change. So

```
UIManager.put("FileChooser.cancelButtonText", "NewValue");
 SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(Filechoose);
```

Will work, but I have to rename `JFileChooser Filechoose1 = new JFileChooser();` 
FileChoose1, FileCoose2 etc. And that is work around that will do. But isnt there any method, like there is setApproveButtonText ?

Comment: direct way is to change a key in UIManager

Answer (score 2):

You can find more info if you check [this](http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/13699-filechooser-ui.html) discussion.

Basically, this is how you solve that, as far as I can figure out:

```
 UIManager.put("FileChooser.cancelButtonText", "Cancel");
 SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(Filechoose);
```

Comment: That will change all occurrences of FileChooser on that form.