# How do I change the text of a JFileChooser instance's button?

Tags: java, swing

I have two `JFileChooser` instances in my app: one for saving and another one for loading. The default "Save" button works fine in the former case but is semantically wrong in the latter. How do I change button text for a **particular `JFileChooser` instance**? Please note that things like

```java
 UIManager.put("FileChooser.cancelButtonText", "Cancel");
 SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(Filechoose);
```

won't work since they will change button text of all instances (the example is from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32054155/change-text-value-of-jfilechooser)). If it's not possible, what are the workarounds?

Comment: JFileChooser has two dialogs.  Should be showOpenFileDialog() and showSaveFileDialog().

Comment: Also, it is in your best interest to peruse [all of the methods of JFileChooser](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#method-summary).

Comment: Also demonstrated in [How to Use File Choosers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)

Comment: @pcalkins thank you! But still, how do I change that (without affecting all the instances)?

Comment: those are methods of the instances so you're fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in function for that kind of thing.

You either need to build your own file chooser which is not perfect idea.

I made a quick function to change name of any button

```
private void changeButtonName(Container fc, String oldValue, String newValue) {
        for (Component item : fc.getComponents()) {
            if (item instanceof  JButton) {
                JButton button = (JButton) item;
                if (button.getText() != null && button.getText().length() > 0 && button.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(oldValue)) {
                    button.setText(newValue);
                }
            }

            if (item instanceof Container) {
                changeButtonName((Container)item, oldValue, newValue);
            }
        }
    }
```

then you can just call it like that:

```
final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

changeButtonName(fc,"cancel", "new_cancel");
```

Keep in mind that I didn't test it extensively